# WP_Query with "post_title LIKE 'something%'"?

Tags: wp-query, sql

I need to do a `WP_Query` with a `LIKE` on the `post_title`.

I started with this regular `WP_Query`:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 
    array (
        'post_type'        => 'wp_exposants',
        'posts_per_page'   => '1',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'orderby'          => 'title', 
        'order'            => 'ASC',
        'paged'            => $paged
    )
);
```

But what I actually want to do looks like this in SQL:

```
$query = "
        SELECT      *
        FROM        $wpdb->posts
        WHERE       $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$param2%'
        AND         $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'wp_exposants'
        ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title
";
$wpdb->get_results($query);
```

The output prints the results i'm excpecting, but I use the regular `<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>` to display the results.
And that is not working with `$wpdb->get_results()`.

How can I achieve what I described here?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I would solve this with a filter on `WP_Query`. One that detects an extra query variable and uses that as the prefix of the title.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function wpse18703_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpse18703_title = $wp_query->get( 'wpse18703_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $wpse18703_title ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

This way you can still call `WP_Query`, you just pass the title as the `wpse18703_title` argument (or change the name to something shorter).

Comment: This one is somehow missing the `$wpdb->prepare()`.

Comment: @kaiser: It's been a long time, but I think this was not possible with `prepare()`. `$wpdb->prepare('LIKE "%s%%"', 'banana')` would return `"LIKE ''banana'%'"`, so we have to construct the query ourselves, and do the escaping too.

Comment: @JanFabry Happy to see you agaaaaaaaain! :) Drop by in chat some time, hm? StopPress would be happy to see you. About that `prepare()`. Yeah, that's tricky and I had to try that several times, before I got around it. From something I just made: `$wpdb->prepare( ' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE %s ', esc_sql( '%'.like_escape( trim( $term ) ).'%' ) )`. And I'm pretty sure the `esc_sql()` is unnecessary and just paranoid.

Comment: It seems that you can't search a string with `'` (apostrophe) inside. I guess it's because of escaping ? I didn't find the solution yet

Comment: I had to remove the `&` from `&$wp_query` otherwise I was getting a PHP `expected to be a reference, value given` error

Answer (score 24):

Simplified:

```
function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    // 2. pull the custom query in here:
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => $page_size,
    'paged' => $page,
    // 1. define a custom query var here to pass your term through:
    'search_prod_title' => $search_term,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'     => 'title', 
    'order'       => 'ASC'
);

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10 );
return $wp_query;
```

Comment: Please include an explanation along with your code.

Comment: Great simplification

Comment: Code is i think self explained, atleast for me. Thanks for sharing complete script.

Comment: Use '$wpdb->esc_like (' instead of 'esc_sql( like_escape('

Comment: @fdrv You are right but according to wp docs $wpdb->esc_like still need esc_sql(). So  I think the correct code would be esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) )

Comment: `like_escape` deprecated 4.0.0 Use `wpdb::esc_like`

Comment: `remove_filter` only uses 3 arguments, the last one can be removed.

Comment: got the above to work but for some reason when I ran my search it was returning data from other post_types even though I'd specified the post type in the $args array.  Ended up adding it to the title query which worked for me `$where .= ' OR ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term )  . '%\' AND '. $wpdb->posts . '.post_type = \'huguenot-family\'';`

Answer (score 21):

Wanted to update this code you guys worked on for the wordpress 4.0 and above as esc_sql() is deprecated in 4.0 higher.

```
function title_filter($where, &$wp_query){
    global $wpdb;

    if($search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_title' )){
        /*using the esc_like() in here instead of other esc_sql()*/
        $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like($search_term);
        $search_term = ' \'%' . $search_term . '%\'';
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE '.$search_term;
    }

    return $where;
}
```

Rest of the stuff is same.

Also I want to point out you can use **s** variable within WP_Query arguments to pass search terms, which will also search for post title i believe.

Like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    's' => $search_term,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'     => 'title', 
    'order'       => 'ASC'        
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: What exactly `search_prod_title` is? Should i change this to something else?

Comment: Since when is `esc_sql` depricated? It's not. `$wpdb->escape` is though... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/

Comment: Note that the s parameter searches the post content as well, which may not be the desired aim. =)

Comment: `like_escape` deprecated `4.0.0` Use `wpdb::esc_like`

Answer (score 18):

With some vulnerable solution posted here, I come with a bit simplified and sanitized version.

First, we create a function for the `posts_where` filter which allows you to only show posts matching specific conditions:

```
function cc_post_title_filter($where, &$wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'cc_search_post_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Now we add `cc_search_post_title` into our query arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'cc_search_post_title' => $search_term, // search post title only
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
```

And finally wrap the filter around the query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cc_post_title_filter', 10, 2 );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'cc_post_title_filter', 10 );
```

## Using get_posts()

Certain functions which retrieve posts do not run filters, so the posts_where filter functions you attach will not modify the query. If you plan to use `get_posts()` to query your posts, you need to set `suppress_filters` to false in your argument array:

```
$args = array(
    'cc_search_post_title' => $search_term,
    'suppress_filters' => FALSE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
```

Now you can use `get_posts()`:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cc_post_title_filter', 10, 2 );
$posts = get_posts($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'cc_post_title_filter', 10 );
```

## What about the `s` parameter?

The `s` parameter is available:

```
$args = array(
    's' => $search_term,
);
```

While adding your search term into the `s` parameter work and it will search the post title, it will *also* search the post content.

## What about the `title` parameter which was added with WP 4.4?

Passing a search term into the `title` parameter:

```
$args = array(
    'title' => $search_term,
);
```

Is case sensitive and `LIKE`, not `%LIKE%`. This mean search for `hello` will not return post with title `Hello World` or `Hello`.

Comment: Excellent. I was looking for 'post_title' as a parameter and, obviously, didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm getting an error with wp query or get posts: "E_WARNING Error in file »class-wp-hook.php« at line 288: Parameter 2 to cc_post_title_filter() expected to be a reference, value given

Comment: @Elkrat Remove the `&` from `&$wp_query` in `cc_post_title_filter`.

Answer (score 8):

Building on other answers before me, to provide flexibility in the situation where you want to search a post that contains a word in a meta field OR in the title of the post, I give that option via the argument "title_filter_relation." In this implementation, I only allow for "OR" or "AND" inputs with a default of "AND."

```
function title_filter($where, &$wp_query){
    global $wpdb;
    if($search_term = $wp_query->get( 'title_filter' )){
        $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like($search_term); //instead of esc_sql()
        $search_term = ' \'%' . $search_term . '%\'';
        $title_filter_relation = (strtoupper($wp_query->get( 'title_filter_relation'))=='OR' ? 'OR' : 'AND');
        $where .= ' '.$title_filter_relation.' ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE '.$search_term;
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Here's an example of the code in action for a very simple post type "faq" where the question is the post title itself:

```
add_filter('posts_where','title_filter',10,2);
$s1 = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'title_filter' => $q,
    'title_filter_relation' => 'OR',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'     => 'title', 
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'faq_answer',
            'value' => $q,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
remove_filter('posts_where','title_filter',10,2);
```

Comment: Good insight, adding custom "query vars" to the query args passed to `WP_Query` in order to be able to access them within the `posts_where` filter.

Comment: seems like a good answer, the only problem is that it's not working for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach for conducting a **WP_Query** with a '**LIKE**' search on the **post_title** is to include the '**search_columns**' query argument. If you are constructing the WP_Query manually, you should specify it as follows:

```php
'search_columns' => ['post_title']
```

You can find more details in the WordPress source code on Trac: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1426

**However**, if your intention is to modify queries generated by **third-party** plugins or themes created query, you can achieve this by leveraging the '**post_search_columns**' filter hook. 
The official documentation provides comprehensive information on how to use this hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_search_columns/