# Search with filters and title

Tags: filters, search, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to search in `custom_post` by title and by the ACF fields.

So, I used the `WP_Query` WordPress function but I can't filter by the title, just by the filters.

When I submit my form, I have this kind of URL:

```
http://example.com/?s=titre&filter1=condition1&filter2=condition2&filter3=condition3
```

My code:

```
$title = $_GET['s'];
$args = array(
    'pagename' => $title,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'filter_1',
            'value' => $_GET['condition_1']
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'filter_2',
            'value' => $_GET['condition_2']
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'filter_3',
            'value' => $_GET['condition_3']
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Do you have any idea to include the title in the search ?

Comment: This is possible a duplicate of this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are setting `$_GET['filterN']` but you are trying to use `$_GET['condition_N']`. That is not ever going to work right.

Secondly, `pagename` is an "exact match" value, not a search parameter, and it ***only*** works with the "Page" post type (at least so far as I can tell). You are using a CPT and, presumably, you do not want an exact match. If you did the other query conditions would pointless. So that isn't going to work correctly either.

The simplest thing you can do is the use the `s` parameter.

```
$title = esc_textarea( $_GET['s'] );
$args = array(
    's'           => $title,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'my_custom_post',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'filter_1',
            'value' => esc_attr( $_GET['filter1'] )
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'filter_2',
            'value' => esc_attr( $_GET['filter2'] )
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'filter_3',
            'value' => esc_attr( $_GET['filter3'] )
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That *will* search the post title for your `$title` string. It will also search `post_content`. To only search the title you will need to filter the search part of the query.

```
function only_title_search_wpse_119422( $search ) {
    remove_filter( 'posts_search', 'only_title_search_wpse_119422' );

    global $wpdb;

    $pattern = "/\({$wpdb->posts}.post_title[^)]+\)/";
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $search, $matches );

    if ( ! empty( $matches[0] ) ) {
        $search = sprintf(
            " AND (%s)",
            implode( " AND ", $matches[0] )
        );
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'only_title_search_wpse_119422' );
```

Add that immediately before your secondary query runs.

I can't tell for sure, but I wonder if you shouldn't be using a filter on `pre_get_posts` instead of the secondary query. The same basic ideas should apply in either case.

*Note: Always use the [`esc_*()`](http://queryposts.com/?s=esc_) and other sanitization methods before using `$_REQUEST/$_GET/$_POST` values in database calls.*