# wp query by search in titles only & put the posts in loop

Tags: wp-query

i need to get posts by search in posts title only not search in full post & put the posts in loop to show it in a slider

**Note : i need to get posts by keyword in title & put it in loop to showing it, not limiting search in all of the site**

i used `wp_query` to do that but it is get posts by searching in full post "content&title"

```
 <?php $query = new WP_Query( 's=mykeyword&cat=22,32&order=dsc&showposts=6' ); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

how can i do that

Comment: You question is self-contradicting. Please explain your problem better.

Comment: i have updated the q i think it is very clear now

Comment: why did you delete the previous question (120165) with the same code ?

Comment: @birgire because it is marked as duplicated & this is not true

Comment: The filter callback from [this question/answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119432/21376) should do what you need.

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/Captialization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i have already solved this problem but now i have anew int this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120193/assign-2-args-to-one-wp-query
@@kaiser sorry for my poor english if you found any spelling, grammar mistakes please edit my question & i will accept your edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to limit the filter from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11826/73) (add that function to your plugin or your theme’s `functions.php`) just to one query, remove the filter when you are done:

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        's'         => 'mykeyword myotherkeyword',
        'cat'       => array( 22, 32 ),
        'orders'    => 'DESC',
        'showposts' => 6
    )
);

remove_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500 );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        the_title( '<p>', '</p>' );
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: "*please post the full code with while loop & if condition like my code*" - WPSE is a **question and answer** site, not a **support forum**. If you need that level of hand-holding, you might be better-served looking for paid support somewhere.

Comment: @ChipBennett thanks for your very very useful information

Comment: thanks man it works fine for me, can i please update my question & put the full solution to every body who searched for?

Comment: @adnan Just [accept the answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can also edit my answer with missing parts. Answers should never be part of the question text.

Comment: a nother thing please can i use this to matching 2 kewords i have tied s=mykeyword,anotherkeyword but it is not working

Comment: @adnan Yes, but you should use a different syntax for `WP_Query`. See my update.

Comment: i mean that 2 different kewords not 1 keyword with 2 words

Comment: @adnan Since version 3.7, WordPress will treat two space separated words as two keywords if there not enough exact matches.

Comment: i tried "'s'         => array( keword1, keword2)," but not worked iam using version 3.5

Comment: @adnan Look at my code. Use a simple string for your search.

Comment: not matching any posts

Comment: @adnan Then ask a new question for that, because it is a separate problem.

Comment: You could try `s=hello+world&sentence=1` vs `s=hello+world&sentence=0`, if that doesn't work try asking a new question on that problem.

Comment: does hello the first keyword & world the second or the sentence is the second