# assign 2 $args to one wp_query

Tags: wp-query, array

i need to excute posts from 2 search keywords & put all in one loop to showing by using WP-Query i have trying `array_merge` but this not worked for me so my last code is:

**please note: i  need to excute posts from 2 seprated keywords not one keyword containing 2 words & put the posts from keyword1, keyword2 in the same loop**

```
$argssss=array('s'         => 'keyword1');
$argsss=array(
's'         => 'keyword2',
'orders'    => 'DESC',
 'showposts' => 60
);
$argss=array_merge( $argssss, $argsss );    
$queryy = new WP_Query($argss);

if ( $queryy->have_posts() ) :
while ( $queryy->have_posts() ) :
    $queryy->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
    the_title( '<p>', '</p>' );
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

i have also tried to put `s` in array but not worked like this `array('keyword1','keyword2')`

so how can i excute posts from 2 different keywords

this answer is very very good it solved my problem by merging 2 wp_query in one 
[Combining queries with different arguments per post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type)

**another note this answer is very very good because it is really merged the two `wp_query` in one but i can't figure it with my filter
[Custom query with category exclusion and post-meta "whitelist"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98652/custom-query-with-category-exclusion-and-post-meta-whitelist/98748#98748)**

but how can i use pagenavi with my custom query

Comment: well why dont you just keep one array and use s like "s"=>$keyword1 . " " . $keyword2

Comment: "s"=>keyword1 . " " . keyword2 , unfortunately not worked

Comment: `but how can i use pagenavi with my custom query` should probably be it's own question as it is unrelated to your first issue. And the answer (or link to it) is in the [WP_Pagnavi FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/faq/) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`array_merge` does not work the way you expect/need it to, but honestly I am not sure why you are making this so complicated. All you need is:

```
$args = array(
  's'         => 'keyword1 keyword2',
  'orders'    => 'DESC',
  'showposts' => 60
);
// var_dump($args); // debug
$query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($query->request); // debug
```

The built is search parser will break the `s` string on the spaces and construct a functional query for the terms.

Comment: +1 - perfect answer - WP_Query takes care of the OR for all keywords listed.

Comment: yasterday i have tried your code without var_dump not worked, now i have tried var_dump & recieved this error "string(309) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%keyword1%') AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%keyword2%')) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 60"

Comment: i have recieved 2 posts with this error every post is containing the 2 keywords

Comment: The `var_dump` data is not an error. It is print-out of the actual SQL used by the query. It is debugging information. That is why there is a comment next to that line that reads `debug`. Comment or remove that line in your final working code. As for your second comment... no idea what that means.

Comment: you are right this is not error sorry, i have achived my goal & updated the question, now i need to use pagenavi with my wp_query

Comment: @adnan If this answered your question (which it seems to have done) don't forget to mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: i appreciate your help but your answer isn't the solution the solution to accept it the solution i have found in this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type

Comment: @Adnan : Your question does not in any way imply that you need that kind of complexity. In fact, the information in the question implies the opposite. That, frankly, makes the answer you found the _wrong_ one not the right one. Even if you did actually need to merge queries a simple `array_merge` is not really the way to do it. That is really an abuse of the `WP_Query` object. There are better ways to do it. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98748/21376

Comment: ok, i will test it but please can you helping me in this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/pagenavi-with-merged-wp-query

Comment: I am pretty sure that that other question has something to do with the abuse of the query object mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: it seems very  very good & it is what exactly i need for some reasons but it is not worked with filters .. unfortunately

Comment: ___What filters?!?!?!?!___ There is no previous mention of filters anywhere in this question. You cannot keep changing the question. Besides which, any appropriate query filter will work with this code. The internals of `WP_Query` are not altered by this code.

Comment: iam sorry you can answered my last question & it is expalined every thing iam really appreciated your help