# pagenavi with merged wp_query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

i need to use wp_query to excute posts from 2 separated keywords using `s=keyword` so i have found this answer & it is very very useful [Combining queries with different arguments per post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type)

& i achieved my goal this is my code

```
<?php add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 ); ?>
<?php
$first=array(
's'         => 'keyword1',
);
$second=array(
's'         => 'keyword2',
);
$first_query = new WP_Query( $first);
$second_query = new WP_Query( $second);
$result = new WP_Query();
$result->posts = array_merge( $first_query->posts, $second_query->posts );
$result->post_count = count( $result->posts );?>
<div class="post-listing">
<?php remove_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500 ); ?>
<?php if ( $result->have_posts() ) : while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post();?>
//layout 
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php if ($result->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but my problem is the pagenavi not worked for me the `<?php if ($result->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>` my theme have a custom pagenavi which authors & categories archive use it

my pagenavi code is

```
<?php
/*
Plugin >> Name: WP-PageNavi
Plugin URI: http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php/
Description: Adds a more advanced paging navigation to your WordPress blog.
Version: 2.50
Author: Lester 'GaMerZ' Chan
Author URI: http://lesterchan.net
*/


/*  
Copyright 2009  Lester Chan  (email : lesterchan@gmail.com)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/


### Function: Page Navigation: Boxed Style Paging
function tie_get_pagenavi($before = '', $after = '') {
global $wpdb, $wp_query;
$pagenavi_options = tie_pagenavi_init(); 

if (!is_single()) {
    $request = $wp_query->request;
    $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
    $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
    $numposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(empty($paged) || $paged == 0) {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    $pages_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_pages']);
    $larger_page_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers']);
    $larger_page_multiple = intval($pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple']);
    $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;
    $half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
    $half_page_end = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
    $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;
    if($start_page <= 0) {
        $start_page = 1;
    }
    $end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;
    if(($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1) {
        $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    }
    if($end_page > $max_page) {
        $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
        $end_page = $max_page;
    }
    if($start_page <= 0) {
        $start_page = 1;
    }
    $larger_per_page = $larger_page_to_show*$larger_page_multiple;
    $larger_start_page_start = (tie_n_round($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple) - $larger_per_page;
    $larger_start_page_end = tie_n_round($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
    $larger_end_page_start = tie_n_round($end_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
    $larger_end_page_end = tie_n_round($end_page, 10) + ($larger_per_page);
    if($larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple == $start_page) {
        $larger_start_page_start = $larger_start_page_start - $larger_page_multiple;
        $larger_start_page_end = $larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple;
    }
    if($larger_start_page_start <= 0) {
        $larger_start_page_start = $larger_page_multiple;
    }
    if($larger_start_page_end > $max_page) {
        $larger_start_page_end = $max_page;
    }
    if($larger_end_page_end > $max_page) {
        $larger_end_page_end = $max_page;
    }
    if($max_page > 1 || intval($pagenavi_options['always_show']) == 1) {
        $pages_text = str_replace("%CURRENT_PAGE%", number_format_i18n($paged), $pagenavi_options['pages_text']);
        $pages_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pages_text);
        //echo $before.'<div class="pagenavi">'."\n";

                if(!empty($pages_text)) {
                    echo '<span class="pages">'.$pages_text.'</span>';
                }
                if ($start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page) {
                    $first_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['first_text']);
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link()).'" class="first" title="'.$first_page_text.'">'.$first_page_text.'</a>';
                    if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'])) {
                        echo '<span class="extend">'.$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'].'</span>';
                    }
                }
                if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_start_page_start > 0 && $larger_start_page_end <= $max_page) {
                    for($i = $larger_start_page_start; $i < $larger_start_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
                        $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
                    }
                }
                previous_posts_link($pagenavi_options['prev_text']);
                for($i = $start_page; $i  <= $end_page; $i++) {                     
                    if($i == $paged) {
                        $current_page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['current_text']);
                        echo '<span class="current">'.$current_page_text.'</span>';
                    } else {
                        $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
                    }
                }
                next_posts_link($pagenavi_options['next_text'], $max_page);
                if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_end_page_start < $max_page) {
                    for($i = $larger_end_page_start; $i <= $larger_end_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
                        $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
                    }
                }
                if ($end_page < $max_page) {
                    if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotright_text'])) {
                        echo '<span class="extend">'.$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'].'</span>';
                    }
                    $last_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['last_text']);
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max_page)).'" class="last" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$last_page_text.'</a>';
                }

        //echo '</div>'.$after."\n";
    }
}
}


### Function: Round To The Nearest Value
function tie_n_round($num, $tonearest) {
return floor($num/$tonearest)*$tonearest;
}


### Function: Page Navigation Options
function tie_pagenavi_init() {
$pagenavi_options = array();
$pagenavi_options['pages_text'] = __('page %CURRENT_PAGE% من %TOTAL_PAGES%','tie');
$pagenavi_options['current_text'] = '%PAGE_NUMBER%';
$pagenavi_options['page_text'] = '%PAGE_NUMBER%';
$pagenavi_options['first_text'] = __('&laquo; first','tie');
$pagenavi_options['last_text'] = __('last &raquo;','tie');
$pagenavi_options['next_text'] = __('next');
$pagenavi_options['prev_text'] = __('prev');
$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'] = __('...','tie');
$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'] = __('...','tie');


$pagenavi_options['num_pages'] = 8;

$pagenavi_options['always_show'] = 0;
$pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers'] = 0;
$pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple'] = 10;

return $pagenavi_options;
}

?>
```

**note please : iam using this code in custom template within single page, the function
`__search_by_title_only` is in my `functions.php` to search only the titles in this query**

**edit when i use `<?php if(function_exists('tie_pagenavi') ) { tie_pagenavi('', '', '', '', 3, false); } ?>` it is show the pagination div `<div class="pagination"></div>` the which available in my categories & authors archives but but in this template the div is empty**

any idea!

Comment: Sounds like you will need to post the code for your customized pagenavi.

Answer (score 1):

The [WP_Pagenavi FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/faq/) links to the following article to explain [how to use the Pagenavi plugin with a secondary query](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html) by passing the `wp_pagenavi()` function a query parameter.

From the tutorial:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    // more stuff here
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );

wp_reset_postdata();    // avoid errors further down the page
```

Comment: but i have pagenavi in my theme so i don't need to install another plugin

Comment: That's a mistake, in my opinion. Where's the benefit? Themes are for *displaying* things. Plugins are for functionality. I'd advise you to take pagenavi our of your theme, and use the plugin... which has the added benefit of getting automatic updates from the repository. At the very least update your version of pagenavi.

Comment: i have a custom theme, custom pagenavi & my pagenavi looks nice

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from styling the actual WP_Pagenavi plugin. You're trying to reinvent the wheel for no reason. Your *version* of "pagenavi" isn't doing what you'd like, so why wouldn't you use a version that does? Or if you insist, you are free to deconstruct WP_Pagenavi for yourself.

Comment: my problem is i don't want to change my category, authors pagenavi if this plugin will do the job without changing category, author pagenavi please let me know

Comment: WP_Pagenavi works on all archives.

Comment: ok, i installed this plugin & it is not overwrited my old pagination in authors & categories, but when i used it in my query i recieved this " Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/core.php on line 217"