# pagenavi shows a lot of pages calculated from all posts in the site with query_posts

Tags: pagination, page-template, get-posts, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I need to execute posts from 2 separated keywords using `s=keyword` with `get_posts`, but only searching in titles. I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles/11826#11826).

I created a custom template to use it in single page. Then I used a merged `get_posts` in my answer using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71576/combining-queries-with-different-arguments-per-post-type/120367#120367)

So, my custom template code is:

```
<?php /* Template Name: custom template posts */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 ); ?>
<?php
//first query
$blogposts = get_posts(array(
    's' => 'keyword1', 'showposts' => -1,
    ));
//second query
$authorposts = get_posts(array(
    's' => 'keyword2', 'showposts' => -1,
    ));
$mergedposts = array_merge( $blogposts, $authorposts ); //combine queries
$postids = array();
foreach( $mergedposts as $item ) {
$postids[]=$item->ID; //create a new query only of the post ids
}
$uniqueposts = array_unique($postids); //remove duplicate post ids
$mypostcount = count($posts);
$posts = get_posts(array(
            //new query of only the unique post ids on the merged queries from above
    'post__in' => $uniqueposts,
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
    ));?>
<?php remove_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500 ); ?>
<div class="post-listing">
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
// layout code here
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page='. $cat_query); ?>
<?php if(function_exists('tie_pagenavi') ) { tie_pagenavi(); } ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I go to Wordpress admin, create new page, and change the default template for it, every thing is okay, but a problem is that my pagination showing a lot of pages as empty after the last page the number of all pages calculated from all posts in my database.

I am using a custom theme which has an internal pagenavi in it called `tie_pagenavi()`. I also tried the `wp_pagenavi` plugin.

**Note:** I am using `$mypostcount = count($posts);` to calculate the number of posts. I tested it by echo. It is really returned by the actual posts number in this loop but I am not sure how to use it to limit the pagination numbers.

You can check every thing by your self in `http://elnhrda.com/e/sisi2posts/page/56/`. 56 is the last page which has posts.

**Edit:** After searching and testing more, the problem is coming from this line

```
query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page='. $cat_query);
```

If I remove it the pagination disappears. If I add `'&showposts=2000'` to it the pages numbers changed the total number of my posts divided into 2000.

Comment: Your issue is with the use of `query_posts()`. Please [use a proper custom query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts), and then modify your question accordingly.

Comment: i have used wp_query before but it isn't achieve my goal with merging ... please suggest a full solution

Comment: "*please suggest a full solution*" - replacing an *improper use* of `query_posts()` with a *proper use* of `WP_Query()` **is a full solution**. If you continue to have problems after implementing it, please update your question with your current code, and describe those issues you're still experiencing.

Comment: because i don't know what is the improper in query posts, so i don't know how to fix it, so i asked you for a full solution, & as i mentioned above i have some problems with `wp_query` in merging sorry for inconvenience

Comment: You can read more about why not to use the `query_posts()` function in its [Codex Function Reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). One Rule of Thumb is: _If you do not know when you should use `query_posts()`, you probably do not know when you should not use it. So, just do not use it._ Many of the people answering questions here have no experience with `query_posts()` at all. We just never user use it.

Comment: i have alot of problems in merging arrays with `wp_query` so i need to use `query_posts` & only fix this issue

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Comment: if you see any mistakes please suggest an edit & i will accept it

Comment: Also, please don't open three [separate](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/pagenavi-with-merged-wp-query) [questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120193/assign-2-args-to-one-wp-query) for what is essentially the same issue. Narrow the scope of your questions, get one resolved, then ask a separate question if you have a related-but-separate problem.

Comment: the previous question is with `wp_query` but this is with `get_posts` i will take care in the future about this, thanks

Comment: ...and `get_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query()`. But the point is: you've opened *three separate questions* to resolve the **same underlying root problem**. You can use the **EDIT** link to *update your question*, as you try various solutions.

Comment: ok, sorry for this & i will take care about this in the future

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after more than 15 hours testing & working

**The Solution is**

replace this line

`query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page='. $cat_query);`

with

`query_posts(array('post__in' => $uniqueposts, 'posts_per_page' => 12,'paged' => $paged,));`

**The Problem is**

this line only responsible for run the pagination so it running it with all number of posts in the site if i not specifying to it which posts i need

Big thanks to every one tried to help me & hope this answer helping some body in the future

Answer (score 1):

I didn't load the plugin to check and I never use `query_posts()`, but perhaps `tie_pagenavi()` is depending on the value in the `$paged` global variable. Try adjusting that value before (or after) calling `query_posts()`. Here is the code to adjust it before calling `query_posts()`.

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
    // On a paged page.
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );

else
    $paged = 1;

query_posts( "paged={$paged}&posts_per_page={$cat_query}" );

if ( function_exists( 'tie_pagenavi' ) )
    tie_pagenavi();
```

Comment: at the top of my code `if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); else $paged = 1;` & after this line `query_posts("paged={$paged}&posts_per_page={$cat_query}");` unfortunately the same thing

Comment: +1 perfect although is doesn't work but +1 is because as you mentioned you don't use `query_posts` although you tried to help, really appreciate this