# WordPress SQL query to tag all posts containing a specific word on title

Tags: query, tags, sql, bulk

Is there a way to bulk tag all posts which have for instance "bottle" in their titles? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did a little bit of searching around this site and found some links that should help you achieve your goal

1) Search all posts that match a specific title 
 - Found this nifty code on another thread [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles/11826#11826) 
 - A use case example of the above function [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120176/wp-query-by-search-in-titles-only-put-the-posts-in-loop)

2) Updating the "tags" for a specific post is fairly simple with this function:

```
  wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'mytagname', 'post_tag', true);
```

3) When you put everything together, it should look something like this (this code is untested)

```
    add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        's'         => 'title_to_search_for'
    )
);

remove_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500 );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
     $post_id = get_the_id();
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'tag_to_add', 'post_tag', true);
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your detailed reply! The problem is that I have thousand and thousand articles so the website gave me a "504 Gateway Time-out". Is there a way to achieve my goal via SQL command in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: '504 Gateway Time-Out' means the php script ran longer than the allotted execution time. use 'set_time_limit()' to increase the execution time, and the script will run fine. you should avoid direct query calls to wp db unless you really know what you're doing.