# WP_Query with meta_value LIKE 'something%'

Tags: wp-query, meta-value

I have read several questions like this (for example, [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something)), but no equal.

I WP_Query need to perform a LIKE on a meta_value. My problem is that I want the like is as follows: meta_value LIKE 'value%' and I can not solve.

My code is as follows:

```
$today = '0702'; /*(month and day)*/

$args = array (
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => $number,
'orderby' => $sort_by,
'cat' => '2'
'post_status' => 'publish'
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
'meta_key' => 'date'
'meta_value' => $today,
'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a left-sided match you can get around the automatic adding of `'%'`'s by WP by using regular expression `RLIKE`:

```
'meta_value' => '^' . preg_quote( $today ),
'meta_compare' => 'RLIKE'
```

Similarly for right-sided match:

```
'meta_value' => preg_quote( $today ) . '$',
'meta_compare' => 'RLIKE'
```