# SQL LIKE in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I am trying to sort a my CPT's so that they are searchable if they are plural or not.  If the name is *digital*, and someone puts in *digitals* they should still get the same results.  I tried using this example [WP_Query with "post_title LIKE 'something%'"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something).  I have it so that it can search; however, if they put the *s* in it returns no results.

This is my Functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wp_enchanced_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function wp_enchanced_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wp_enchanced_title_search = $wp_query->get( 'wp_enchanced_title_search' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $wp_enchanced_title_search ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
```

---

This is my search.php

```
<section class="list-grid">
      <ul>
    <?php  $args_resource = array(
    'orderby'     => 'title',
    'post_type' => 'resource',
    'wp_enchanced_title_search' => $resource
  );
$query_resource = new WP_Query($args_resource);?>
        <?php while ($query_resource->have_posts()) : $query_resource->the_post(); ?>
          <li>
            <div class="list-grid__toggle">
              <a><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>
              <ul class="list-grid__toggle__icons">
                <li><a class="icon-button icon-button--map" href="<?php the_field('map_link'); ?>" target="_blank"><span>Map</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="icon-button icon-button--link" href="<?php the_field('link'); ?>"><span>Link</span></a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="list-grid__toggle__content">
                <div class="list-grid__toggle__content__info">
                  <?php the_field('description'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="list-grid__toggle__content__detail">
                  <?php the_field('additional_information'); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="list-grid__toggle__image" style="background-image: url(<?php $image = get_field('image'); echo $image['sizes']['resource']; ?>);">
                <a class="list-grid__toggle__close"><span>Close</span></a>
              </div>
              <?php if (have_rows('related_links')) : ?>
                <div class="list-grid__toggle__links">
                  <span>Related Links:</span>                
                  <ul>
                    <?php while (have_rows('related_links')) : the_row(); ?>
                      <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>"<?php if (get_sub_field('target')) : ?> target="<?php the_sub_field('target'); ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php the_sub_field('link_text'); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                  </ul>                
                </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple typo in,

```
if ( $wp_enchanced_title_search = $wp_query->get( 'wp_enchanced_title_search' )
```

this can never fire, you should put `==` instead `=`

```
if ( $wp_enchanced_title_search == $wp_query->get( 'wp_enchanced_title_search' )
```

Hope it works !